# In a C function what's the difference between char and string?

Tags: c, string, char

I'm using a template from my teacher and at the beginning of the code is says:

```
#include "lab8.h"

void main(void)
{
int response;
int count;
string words[MAX_COUNT];
```

Later on in the function, a whole lot of words get put inside the words string. So I was like looking at that last line and got confused. I thought char declared strings? What does that last line even do? I also noticed in a couple of function parameter lists later on, there was entered "string words" instead of what I expected that mention char or something.

EDIT:

```
typedef char string[MAX_LENGTH];
```

had been written in the .h file didn't see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C does not have a basic [data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types) called `string`.

Check the `lab8.h` file carefully. Usually, `string` should be a typedef of `unsigned char`.

Essentially, `string words[MAX_COUNT];` defines an array of variable type `string` containing `MAX_COUNT` number of variables.

Comment: `unsigned char` would make `string x` a pretty blatant misnomer. `unsigned char *` would work. For that ambiguity alone, let's find whoever wrote that typedef and have some words with him...

Comment: Yeah I feel dumb now didn't see that   "typedef char string[MAX_LENGTH];"   had been written in the .h file.

Answer (score 0):

C does not have a dedicated string data type.  In C, a *string* is a sequence of character values followed by a zero-valued byte.  Strings are stored as arrays of `char`, but not all arrays of `char` contain strings.

For example,

```
char word[] = { 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 0 };
```

stores the string `"hello"` in the array variable `word`.  The array size is taken from the size of the initializer, which is 6 (5 characters plus the 0 terminator).  The zero-valued byte serves as a sentinel value for string handling functions like `strlen`, `strcpy`, `strcat`, and for arguments to `printf` and `scanf` that use the `%s` and `%[` conversion specifiers.

By contrast,

```
char arr[] = { 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' };
```

stores a sequence of character values, but since there's no terminating 0-valued byte, this sequence is not considered a *string*, and you would *not* want to use it as an argument to any string-handling function (since there's no terminator, the function has no way of knowing where the string ends and will wind up attempting to access memory outside of the array, which can lead to anything from garbage output to a crash).

Without seeing the contents of `lab8.h`, I'm going to speculate that the `string` type is a typedef for an array of `char`, something like

```
#define MAX_STRING_LENGTH 20 // or some other value
typedef char string[MAX_STRING_LENGTH];
```

Thus, an array of `string` is an array of arrays of `char`; it would be equivalent to

```
char words[MAX_COUNT][MAX_STRING_LENGTH];
```

So each `words[i]` is an N-element array of `char`.